# Remove vertices based on texture

Tags: texturing, vertices

Is there a way to apply a black and white texture to a object and remove all vertices mapped to a point where the texture is black?

I want to build a hollow earth globe and remove all vertices where there is land.

Comment: Do you want to actually remove the vertices from the mesh or just hide them so they won't be rendered?

Comment: I want to actually remove them, because it's supposed to be 3d printed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [Create a Vertex Group](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Vertex_Groups#Creating_Vertex_Groups).
2. Add a [Vertex Weight Mix modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Modify/Vertex_Weight#Vertex_Weight_Mix_Modifier).

   - Set *Vertex Group A* to the one created in the previous step.
   - Set *Default Weight B* to 1.
   - Set *Mix Set* to *All*.
   - Add your texture to *Texture Mask* and set *Textue Coordinates*.
3. Add a [Mask modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mask) and set the *Vertex Group*.
4. [Apply modifiers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/The_Stack#Interface) (optional).

[image: The result]

Comment: I added the texture, projected the uv map and created the two vertex groups, but it still didn't work. I know it's something obvious, but I have little experience with blender. Could you please start the answer from the point you add the texture?

Comment: Possible problems: **a)** Have you added the vertices of your object to the vertex groups with the correct values? To do that, go into Edit-mode, select everything, go to one of the vertex groups, set the Weight slider below to 0/1 depending on the group, and then click "Assign". **b)** Do both modifiers look just like above?

Comment: I know the texture is correct (or half correct) because on the 3d view the texture is showing it, but when I render it doesn't. Also the vertex are right because I can select them with the select button.

Comment: For the Texture in the Modifier, click _Texture Mask: + New_, then click on the very right button that appeared (mouseover description: "Show texture in texture tab"), there, set "Type" to "Image or Movie" and open the correct image in the "Image" area below.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10031/discussion-between-lucass-and-julianhzg)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't assigne the weights, and I tried to change them by selecting the vertex group and sliding the weight. I had to assign the groups again with the correct weight. Thanks!!