# Vertex group from texture

Tags: vertex-groups

If I have a model, for instance UV unwrapped, how can I from a texture assign a vertex group. White = assign vertex, black = don't assign vertex, values in between = halfway assigned vertex based on color intensity. A grayscale image would probably be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove vertices based on texture](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/remove-vertices-based-on-texture)

Comment: It is a dubplicate, however the titles are so different I think this one deserves to be here, or does it? Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Gunslinger dups aren't necessarily bad, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ and http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates, it will still "be here", just with a link to another post that answers the same question.

Answer (score 10):

You can try the **Vertex Weight Edit** modifier. For example, I can input the following texture as a *Texture Mask* to the modifier:

[image: texture]

... that will then use its value, to control how the modifier assigns weight to each vertex. Tweak at least the *Default Weight*, threshold settings and fallof type to get the result you need:

[image: modifier]

Though not instantly updated if we edit the image, the result shows up immediately, and is usable by modifiers further down the stack:

[image: weight]

[image]

*Default Weight* and *Add Threshold* should be of that weight which you'd like to have as the end result, *Add Threshold* should be slightly less.

Comment: If you wonder why I hesitate to accept this answer, I can't get it to work for me. Will try more later.

Comment: Check it through weight paint mode, maybe the modifier settings, or its position within the modifier stack (should be above whatever other modifier is using it).

Comment: @Gunslinger , did this ever work for you?  Thanks.

Comment: No, I think I did it another way. I don't remember anymore.

Comment: @Adhi Could you please upload a .blend file with your solution. I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works but is annoying:

1. Create a new vertex group, and in Edit Mode assign all vertices to the group.
2. Back in Object Mode add a VertexWeightEdit Modifier
3. In the Falloff Tab create a custom curve and move the right point to 0.
4. In the Influence Tab add the texture you've already created.

What this does is subtract the texture from the 100% weight of the original group. This means the final selection is the inverse of what you want: lighter parts of the texture are the least selected. So any time you use the Vertex Group you have to enable the invert button (Looks like this: <-> ) to get the result you expect.

[image: Modifiers Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Wow, almost 10 years ago. Time flies. Thanks for the answer, will check it out.