# How to use procedural texture color as vertex group?

Tags: modifiers, weight-painting

Is it possible to convert color intensity of procedural texture to weighs so it can be used as vertex group in modifiers?

Comment: Probably using `Vertex Weight Edit` modifier, that is already described here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3355/vertex-group-from-texture.