# How to use Mesh to paint weight to another

Tags: weight-painting

I need to paint weight on a surface with precision.
Can i put another mesh on my plane and paint it with that?

I have this "gray" plane and this "pink" shape. i want to use the pink shape to weight paint the plane below
[image: Road and Grass field]

Thank You

Comment: Can you expand that question a little more. Are you trying to paint a specific shape?

Comment: Sure, excuse me. Look at the image in my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3355/vertex-group-from-texture/3356#3356

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic paint to do that. Make the plane a canvas, and the pink object a brush, and set the plane's surface type to Weight.

*Note: you should be aware that the resolution of the weight painting depends on the subdivision of the plane*.

[image]

[image]

[image]