# Is it possible to extrude a PNG image?

Tags: image, transparency, animation-nodes, sverchok

Is it possible to extrude a PNG image in Blender? (Perhaps using animation nodes or sverchok?) If Blender can read the alpha, wouldn't it also be possible to draw curves along the edges? (assuming the alpha is completely transparent or completely opaque, (I tried to do this in sverchok but couldn't work it out as I'm completely new to it.)

Comment: I think you'd have more luck converting it to a vector image (e.g., Trace Bitmap in Inkscape) before you import to Blender

Comment: True, just thinking... if Blender already has the alpha edges data, it would be cool if it could then natively draw and extrude the edges.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94602/a-strange-bias-for-vertex-weight-edit-modifier
I'm not quite sure about what you want to do but if it is to "extrude picture depending on it's value" (or alpha or whatever) I think this post would help.

Comment: Using the alpha information on a displace modifier... or use it to feed the displacement socket on a material...

Comment: Interesting, I haven't used that modifier before

Comment: Rather than actually extrude you could generate the appearance of depth as in this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84618/29586

Comment: @cegaton I have done that before but to get clean extrusions the subdivisions need to be really high which isn't ideal