# Optimize viewport for animation

Tags: animation, workflow

Hello to all of the Blender gurus. I would like to ask you a little complicated question.

What is exactly the blender philosophy for work pipeline?

[image: Simply AE scene]

Specific: I worked with 3ds max and maya and I am now trying to change to blender because i dont like autodesk. There are many tools for automating pipeline.

But in blender i challenge basics problems like >

A) Optimize viewport for animation (textures has 5000x5000px) so some kind option for preview (not render) textures optimizing without proxys?

So back to my question, is the philosophy of blender to make it so open, everybody must script their own pipeline from scratch ?

Or I can find somewhere links or answers for this kind pipeline/automation questions.

Comment: There are several questions, you'd better to split them to separate ones. Blender philosophy question isn't fitting rules of this site I think.  As to selecting vertices by alpha of the texture you can use Weight Edit modifier on unwrapped mesh and pick desired texture with UV coordinates and Alpha in modifier's settings, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94602/a-strange-bias-for-vertex-weight-edit-modifier for one example (vertex group will be result of selection). Generally preview of textures is Texture shading mode.

Comment: Thank you for reply,

yes I found this setup but its not what i need because after applying modifier the vertex group isnt from aplha or luma of texture but default like I set. 

And shading mode - there are only few options .. there are no optimize texture for animation - like for render use 5k x 5k but for preview use 256x256 px.

So i asked little bit ... overkill. For me is fine to know, if i am stupid and need to learn more about blender because there for sure are possibilites or .. i must scripting it for my own and i need to learn much more python. Thast the question.

Comment: Thank you very much - problem with my lacking of knowlege about optimizing viewport - solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimize viewport performance limit resolution of textures which are assigned to meshes.

Open User Preferences > *System* tab > *textures* category (scroll down) > *Limit Size*. You can choose appropriate value from the dropdown list, where *Off* is set by default. Read more about [limiting size of textures displayed in the viewport in manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/system.html#textures).

[image: screenshot-user-prefs-texture-perf]

In the example below limit is disabled first and texture isn't affected. Then limit is set to lowest value (126 px) for demostration purposes which makes textures become blurry and less visible.

[image: screenshot-viewport-textures-comparison]

To show textures on your objects in viewport follow steps from this question - [How to show textures in the 3D View editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor) which depend on render engine.