# Trying to make a tapered screw blade

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

I'm trying to make a copy of this rocket engine part from a photograph and I need help with the blades.

[image]

As you can see the blades at the top, increase in thickness as they approach the 90 degree mark, and then decrease in thickness as it completes its rotation at 180 degrees.

Making a blade of uniform thickness is trivial, I just use the screw modifier, but I can't figure out a good way to modify the thickness through the curve.

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94602/a-strange-bias-for-vertex-weight-edit-modifier TL;DR Use the solidify modifier with vertex weights. The weights can be controlled with textures.