# How does the Vertex Weight Mix Modifier Work Internally

Tags: modifiers, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I've gone through all of the documentation and been fiddling around with this modifier for an hour.  Can someone tell me how it works?  What is it actually doing?  My understanding right now is that it mixes different weights (which you set by vertex groups) and I understand all of the blend modes and what not).  Essentially, I understand a lot of what it's doing but I can't wrap my head around this problem.  In the vertex groups you set a weight for your vertex group and then in this modifier you have an A and a B group and you set default weights for the A group and the B group.  What is the interaction between these different weight settings?  How does it work together?  Also, how would you use a texture map on this (I looked up the blender post for this at [Remove vertices based on texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/remove-vertices-based-on-texture--) but couldn't figure it out).

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a slow read through the manual page on the [vertex weight mix modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_mix.html), it has an example at the end to help explain it.

The points I think are most relevant -

> **Vertex Group A**
>       The vertex group to affect.
>   **Default Weight A**
>       The default weight to assign to all vertices not in the given vertex group.
>   **Vertex Group B**
>       The second vertex group to mix into the affected one. Leave it empty if you only want to mix in a simple value.
>   **Default Weight B**
>       The default weight to assign to all vertices not in the given second vertex group.
>
> **Mix Set**
>       Choose which vertices will be affected.
>       **All vertices**
>           Affects all vertices, disregarding the vertex groups content.
>       **Vertices from group A**
>           Affects only vertices belonging to the affected vertex group.
>       **Vertices from group B**
>           Affects only vertices belonging to the second vertex group.
>       **Vertices from one group**
>           Affects only vertices belonging to at least one of the vertex groups.
>       **Vertices from both groups**
>           Affects only vertices belonging to both vertex groups.
>
> **Texture Mask**
>       An additional texture, the values of which will be multiplied with the global influence value for each vertex.

So `Vertex Group A` is the group that gets the result, you use this in modifiers after the mix.

The mix mode defines how the two values are mixed, while the set decides which vertices get the weight.

The texture mask can then limit the result to certain areas of the mesh.

Comment: Thanks for the response @sambler!  So the texture mask that you use basically applies the black and white values for selecting vertices on group A only.  Is that correct?  Also, to do this, would you have to UV unwrap the object from which you are selecting vertices?  Lastly, were you saying that "Vertex Group A" will then show up as its own vertex group when I use it in other modifiers or would I have to specify it as an attribute?  Thanks man!

Comment: GroupA gets the calculated vertex weight, if you have a wave modifier after the weight mix and set its vertgroup to GroupA then the calculated vertex weight will affect the wave. The mix set defines which vertices get the calculated weight assigned to them. UV's have no effect on the vertex weights, they may be used to affect the texture used. In the texture black=0.0 white=1.0, the calculated weights are multiplied by this value, so black parts of the texture mean no weight and white parts mean the full calculated weight.

Comment: Thanks again for the response @sambler!  You fully answered two of my questions, and for the final question, I didn't elaborate so that was my fault.  So say I add a procedural textural ie) noise for the sake of clarity and I want to use that texture to be able to get a weight of 1 where the noise texture is white and 0 where it's black on a cube mesh.  Blender will basically use default texture coordinate mapping of the noise texture to be able to put those weights on there yeah?  And then for example if I wanted to get a weight based on an AO map then I would have to UV unwrap yeah?

Comment: If you have baked an AO map then you will want to use uv's for that image texture. For procedural textures, you can do either. For any texture you can choose a mapping type of generated, object, uv, world, camera...

Comment: Awesome that makes sense.  Thanks for the help!